# [endfloat][classicthesis] Force floats to end of pdf, but keep numbering per chapter (two versions of document pdf)

Tags: classicthesis, endfloat

Like in [this question,](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/406831/force-floats-to-end-of-pdf-but-keep-numbering-per-chapter-two-versions-of-docu) I would like to postpone figures to the end of the document (the aim of endfloat) but to have a chapter-based numbering of Figures. The solution given as answer works on simple document, but if I use `classicthesis.sty`, I loose chapter numbers in Figure numbering/caption.

Here is a *minimal* code.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[floatperchapter]{classicthesis} % ,manychapters
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[nomarkers,nofiglist]{endfloat}

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{endfloat}
{
 \efloat@condopen{fff}
 \pretocmd\@chapter{\immediate\write\efloat@postfff{\noexpand\stepcounter{chapter}}}{}{\fail}
 \AtBeginFigures{\setcounter{chapter}{0}}
}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}

\lipsum[1-1]

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \fbox{CHAPTER: 1 -- FIGURE: 1 -- ref=\ref{c1:f1}}
  \caption{chapter 1 -- figure 1}
  \label{c1:f1}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2-2]

\begin{figure}
  \centering    
  \fbox{CHAPTER: 1 -- FIGURE: 2  -- ref=\ref{c1:f2}}
  \caption{chapter 1 -- figure 2}
  \label{c1:f2}    
\end{figure}

\lipsum[3-3]

\chapter{Second Chapter}

\lipsum[4-4]

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \fbox{CHAPTER: 2 -- FIGURE: 1 --  ref=\ref{c2:f1}}
  \caption{chapter 2 -- figure 1}
  \label{c2:f1}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[5]

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \fbox{CHAPTER: 2 -- FIGURE:  2 -- ref=\ref{c2:f2}}
  \caption{chapter 2 -- figure 2}
  \label{c2:f2}    
\end{figure}

\lipsum[6]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried loading classicthesis just before \begin{document}?

Comment: @PhilipPirrip Yes I tried  loading classicthesis before loading endfloat (as in the example), just after loading endfloat, and just before `\begin{document}`.

Comment: I've just tested your ME: I do see chapter numbers on pages 1 and 3, and four "figures" on pages 4-7. Using classicthesis v4.6, TeX Live on Fedora Linux 33.

Comment: @PhilipPirrip My description of the problem was unclear. Sorry. I have updated it. The problem is to have chapter numbering in caption of Figures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're patching the wrong command.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[nomarkers,nofiglist]{endfloat}
\usepackage[floatperchapter]{classicthesis} % ,manychapters

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{endfloat}{%
    \efloat@condopen{fff}%
    \pretocmd\caption@chapter@ORI{\immediate\write\efloat@postfff{\noexpand\stepcounter{chapter}}}{}{}%
    \AtBeginFigures{\setcounter{chapter}{0}}%
  }{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}

\lipsum[1-1]

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \fbox{CHAPTER: 1 -- FIGURE: 1 -- ref=\ref{c1:f1}}
  \caption{chapter 1 -- figure 1}
  \label{c1:f1}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2-2]

\begin{figure}
  \centering    
  \fbox{CHAPTER: 1 -- FIGURE: 2  -- ref=\ref{c1:f2}}
  \caption{chapter 1 -- figure 2}
  \label{c1:f2}    
\end{figure}

\lipsum[3-3]

\chapter{Second Chapter}

\lipsum[4-4]

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \fbox{CHAPTER: 2 -- FIGURE: 1 --  ref=\ref{c2:f1}}
  \caption{chapter 2 -- figure 1}
  \label{c2:f1}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[5]

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \fbox{CHAPTER: 2 -- FIGURE:  2 -- ref=\ref{c2:f2}}
  \caption{chapter 2 -- figure 2}
  \label{c2:f2}    
\end{figure}

\lipsum[6]

\end{document}
```

*No rooster was harmed to perform the black magic.*

Comment: Great. Thank you very much.